# How do I use Twitter Bootstrap with 2 versions of jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drupal-6

What is the best way to use Twitter Bootstrap along side an older version of jQuery?

I have a drupal 6 site and a Bootstrap based responsive theme that works quite well, but they each need their own version of Jquery. I have looked at implementing things using `noconflict` but I can't find a straight forward example of that in this kind of scenario - which made me wonder if that is the correct approach at all.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just fix up whatever breaks on Drupal? There aren't many breaking changes in jQuery.

Comment: That is my preferred method, but I don't think its reasonable in this case, with my timeline - Drupal 6 tops out at jQuery 1.3.2 - and this site is quite large with a number of modules depending on the core Jquery in drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include jquery 1.9.1, include bootstrap, then include the following:

```
<script>
    var $_191 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Or, even better, update drupal to include jQuery 1.9.1 + jQuery migrate

---

Edit: updating from 1.3.2 to 1.9.1 will take more than just adding jQuery migrate most likely, i wouldn't suggest attempting it unless you had a little bit of time to work through the bugs.

Comment: Thanks - yes time is a factor, as is the size of the site. Otherwise, I'd start by moving to Drupal 7. :) The use of Bootstrap/jquery functionality is minimal, so the noconflict approach *is* looking like the best approach after all, Although it seems almost too easy/magical - I'm interested to see if it really works.

Comment: ... and it worked. I think its worth noting that the Bootstrap method of loading files at the bottom of the page helps here, with Drupal loading everything initially. Also, that it didn't really require anything else be done.